# ATMega2561 - How to connect this ambient light sensor using 1-Wire?

Tags: avr, atmega, light-sensor, 1-wire

I am trying to connect the following components to an AVR ATMega2561:

- 1-Wire Master Interface DS2484 [datasheet here](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2484.pdf)
- RGB Ambient Light Sensor APDS-9250 [datasheet here](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-4733EN)

I have already managed to connect the 1-Wire interface, but I am now wondering if I can connect the light sensor as a slave through the 1-Wire interface, or do I need to use I2C for both the interface and the sensor?

Here's an image of the sensor's symbol without going too deep into the documentation:
[image]

Is there a component I am missing that would let me connect it using the 1-Wire interface? Or do these two components (1-Wire Master interface and the sensor) have to be connected independently, both using I2C (SCL, SDA)?

I apologize if this is a pretty basic question, but I've been searching online for quite some time and I couldn't find anything. I also looked for other light sensors with 1-Wire but I couldn't find any - some temperature or humidity sensors can use 1-Wire, but I didn't find any ambient light sensors that do.

Comment: Search for "1-Wire-to-I2C Master Bridge". There are standard products that do exactly what you want, or you could program a small (6-pin or 8-pin) MCU to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use DS2484 this way. As per it's datasheet general description section:

> The DS2484 is an I2C-to-1-WireM bridge device that
> interfaces directly to standard (100kHz max) or fast
> (400kHz max) I2C masters to perform protocol conversion between the **I2C master** and any **downstream 1-Wire slave** devices

And there is a schematic below:

[image: DS2484 schematic]

It works the other way. You interface it with I2C from MCU (the master) and it allows to communication with 1-Wire slave devices. Your APDS-9250 are I2C slave device just as the DS2484. Most MCUs, including ATMega2561 have I2C master interface. You can use it to directly attach the APDS-9250 to your I2C interface.

If you still need to use DS2484 (no for the APDS-9250), you can attach it on the same I2C bus. But make sure that slave addresses will be different. Other way it to implement either 1-Wire or 2nd I2C interface in software.